# Variadic templates without function parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, function-parameter

Can I use variadic templates without using the template parameters as function parameters?

When I use them, it compiles:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class First>
void print(First first)
{
    cout << 1 << endl;
}

template<class First, class ... Rest>
void print(First first, Rest ...rest)
{
    cout << 1 << endl;
    print<Rest...>(rest...);
}

int main()
{
    print<int,int,int>(1,2,3);
}
```

But when I don't use them, it doesn't compile and complains about an ambiguity:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class First>
void print()
{
    cout << 1 << endl;
}

template<class First, class ... Rest>
void print()
{
    cout << 1 << endl;
    print<Rest...>();
}

int main()
{
    print<int,int,int>();
}
```

Unfortunately the classes I want to give as template parameters are not instantiable (they have static functions that are called inside of the template function).
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you need an *unevaluated* expression of a given type, you can use `std::declval<T>()`. Works for any `T`, whether or not its constructible.

Comment: As for why the no-argument version doesn't work: Without arguments, both overloads `print<int, {}>` and `print<int>` are equally good, while with arguments `print<int>(3)` is a better match than `print<int, {}>(3, {})` (where `{}` means "nothing"). Not using overloads, as CatPusPus suggests, is the standard method; and since you're not deducing your arguments anyway it's the simplest solution.

Comment: I was going to post an answer but n.m. already posted it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
template<class First> // 1 template parameter
void print()
{
    cout << 1 << endl;
}

#if 0
template<class First, class ... Rest> // >=1 template parameters -- ambiguity!
void print()
{
    cout << 1 << endl;
    print<Rest...>();
}
#endif

template<class First, class Second, class ... Rest> // >=2 template parameters
void print()
{
    cout << 1 << endl;
    print<Second, Rest...>();
}
```

Comment: You can get rid of the code duplication by invoking `print<First>()` from that bottom-most version, instead of repeating the `cout` line. I think.

Answer (score 8):

Make it a type.

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct print_impl;

template <typename T>
struct print_impl<T> {
    static void run() {
        std::cout << 1 << "\n";
    }
};

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct print_impl<T, Ts...> {
    static void run() {
        std::cout << 1 << "\n";
        print_impl<Ts...>::run();
    }
};

template <typename... Ts>
void print() {
    print_impl<Ts...>::run();
}

int main() {
    print<int, int, int>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the complexity here is not merited. n.m.'s solution is much more straightforward.