# Error deducing variadic function template

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I'm having a problem with the type deduction of variadic template functions. Here is what I'm trying to do:

I have a template class which works as an allocator. In order to choose the right allocator, I need some information about the type parameters. The information is collected in a vector.

The functions creating the actual meta data look like this:

```
template<typename T> 
MetaData* create_meta() { 
    return new DefaultMetaData(); 
}

template<MyExampleType> 
MetaData* create_meta() { 
    return new MyExampleTypeMetaData(); 
}

template<MyOtherType> 
MetaData* create_meta() { 
    etc. 
}
```

And the function collecting the meta data looks like this right now:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void fill_meta_data(std::vector<MetaData*> &meta) { 
    meta.push_back(create_meta<T>()); 
    fill_meta_data<Args...>(meta);
}
```

edit: Trying to clearify the problem:

I want to call the `fill_meta_data` function like this:

```
fill_meta_data<MyExampleType, MyExampleType, MyOtherType>(meta_data_vector)
```

And as a result the meta_data_vector to contain Meta Data for MyExampleType, MyExampleType and MyOtherType

The error I'm getting is "template argument deduction/substitution failed: couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'".

I think that the problem occurs when it tries to deduce the argument for the no-arg version, however, I just can't figure out how to define this default (where it should just return).

I already tried `template<>` (which is not recognized), `template<typename... Args>` (the compiler says there are two implementations for more than 0 parameters).

Different solutions for the problem would also be welcome :)

Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks to @catscradle's link: 
Here is a solution which worked for me:

I had to add the template

```
template<typename... Args>
typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Args) == 0>::type
fill_meta_data(std::vector<MetaData*> &meta) {}
```

which is only enabled when the size of the Args parameters is zero.

Thanks everybody!

Comment: It is very hard to follow what you are trying to do. Why are you calling `fill_meta_data` recursively? Is my understanding correct that you have different meta data containers and also different creation policies? If so, why do you need variable argument templates? Can you talk more about the problem you are trying to solve (not about the code you are using to solve it).

Comment: About you example code “`template<MyExampleType> MetaData* create_meta()`” didn't you rather mean `template<> MetaData* create_meta<MyExampleType>()` (explicit specialization)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758620/variadic-function-template-without-formal-parameters

Answer (score 0):

There's a few syntax errors in your code, but there shouldn't be a problem once you sort them out.

Your function specializations are wrong.  Instead of:

```
template<typename T> 
MetaData* create_meta() { 
    return new DefaultMetaData(); 
}

template<MyExampleType> 
MetaData* create_meta() { 
    return new MyExampleTypeMetaData(); 
}
```

Try:

```
template<typename T> 
MetaData* create_meta() { 
    return new DefaultMetaData(); 
}

template <>
MetaData* create_meta<MyExampleType>() { 
    return new MyExampleTypeMetaData(); 
}
```

The other issue is that your recursion doesn't have a final function.  Some find it helpful to draw out recursion so it makes more sense.  If we draw out your recursion with some types, we might get this:

```
fill_meta_data<short, int, long> // T = short, Args... = int, long
fill_meta_data<int, long>        // T = int, Args... = long
fill_meta_data<long>             // T = long, Args... = 
fill_meta_data<>                 // T = ???, Args... =
```

You can see that the final step is undefined because T has no meaning, but it needs an input.  So, to "close off" your recursive template function you'll just need a regular function overload with no arguments that does nothing:

```
void fill_meta_data(std::vector<MetaData*> &meta) { 
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void fill_meta_data(std::vector<MetaData*> &meta) { 
    meta.push_back(create_meta<T>()); 
    fill_meta_data<Args...>(meta);
}
```